# What's a Reasonable Length of Time to Timeout a Ruby Thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, timeout, network-protocols

I've got a need to retain the data and keep a Ruby program waiting for a response for anything up to a couple of days. I'm thinking about implementing this using threads (there may be a number of concurrent requests across a network). My question; is it reasonable to leave a thread running for anything up to a couple of days awaiting a response?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Computer's don't get bored.

Comment: Depends on what it's doing, really. If the **expected** time was a second or two, a day-long timeout would be excessive.

Comment: I'm sending a message over the network and awaiting a response. That response depends on a asynchronous API that can take a couple of days to respond, hence the long wait. I'd timeout sooner if that weren't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no problem with that. Check out the Queue class, it might facilitate the "job polling":

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the answer. The Queue class _does_ look pretty interesting for what I need; good call!